# mvn install produces compilation error for @Getter @Setter properties for Lombok properties

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, lombok

I encountered this when I was testing my application an mvn test would not run and produce compilation issues specifically at the properties which have the @Getter @Setter annotations of Lombok. There are no highlighting errors in the IDE as the Intelij plugin works but somehow maven is not able to find Lombok. I've seen posts that were similar to my issue but all of them had a different version of maven / lombok / maven-compiler. My Versions are Maven - 3.5 , Maven compiler - 3.7 , Lombok 1.16.20.

My Java Class with lombok anotations

```
@JsonProperty
@Getter @Setter private String name;


@JsonProperty
@Getter @Setter private String catType;


@JsonProperty
@Getter @Setter private String description;


@JsonProperty
@Getter @Setter private String intType;


@JsonProperty
@Getter @Setter private String numberCode;
```

when I run mvn install I get

```
> [my-path]/my-java.java:[86,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method numberCode()
[ERROR]   location: variable source of type My-java
[my-path]/my-java.java:[86,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method name()
[ERROR]   location: variable source of type My-java
[my-path]/my-java.java:[86,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method catType()
[ERROR]   location: variable source of type My-java
[my-path]/my-java.java:[86,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method description()
[ERROR]   location: variable source of type My-java
```

Here Is my Pom.xml (as this was a very lengthy pom.xml I only shared what might matter in the context of this question)

```
    <lombok.version>1.18.0</lombok.version>
 <maven-clean-plugin.version>2.6.1</maven-clean-plugin.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.7.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-eclipse-plugin.version>2.10</maven-eclipse-plugin.version>
        <maven-enforcer-plugin.version>3.0.0-M1</maven-enforcer-plugin.version>
        <maven-resources-plugin.version>3.0.1</maven-resources-plugin.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.18.1</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
          <maven.version>3.0.0</maven.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <scala.version>2.12.1</scala.version>
        <node.version>v8.9.4</node.version>
        <yarn.version>v1.3.2</yarn.version>

  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Ad your POM please.

Comment: What IDE are you using? Also would like to know, if lombok plugin is installed in your IDE(not only as a dependency in pom.xml).

Comment: Maven doesn't provide a compiler, it falls back on javac. Provide your pom to analyze your issue.

Comment: @Reborn I am using IntelliJ 2018 idea community edition , Yes I have installed IntelliJ Lombok plugin.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza i meant <maven-compiler-plugin.version>

Comment: @DarrenForsythe added please tell me if you want to see the whole pom.xml

Comment: Do you have anything else doing annotation processing?

Comment: @DarrenForsythe well,This is a Jhipster project with spring boot. Spring would do annotation processing right?

Comment: @DarrenForsythe I'm also using mapstruct

Comment: @DarrenForsythe you are right adding another annotationProcessorPaths was causing this issue

Comment: @MahiTejGvp if you use the latest version of mapstruct it should seemlessly integrate without the need to specify the annotation processor paths manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing the comment from @DarrenForsythe I removed mapstruct annotationProcessorPaths from the configurations of maven-compiler It works just fine. **If you are using any other annotation processors that may result in a conflict**

Answer (score 0):

This might help you: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1468
Check if you have any of this problems:

1. Method with identical signature defined twice in same class, or
   variable with identical name defined twice in same class
2. Name of public class doesn't match name of file it is defined in

   by gkostalkowicz github

Comment: hey @Mateusz Byczkowski I think This is not the same

Answer (score -1):

Did you add project lombok dependency in your pom.xml file ?

If not done already, try adding :

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.20</version>
        </dependency>
```

and see if that helps.

Good Day!

Comment: hey @dossani I added it